# Programming a BST for Morse code decryption

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, morse-code

I'm working on a project in which I'm supposed to develop a set of classes to implement a BST that allows me to code a word in Morse code and translate Morse code to alphanumeric format.

I've been provided with the following:
BST generic implementation -> https://pastebin.com/mGLY2V25

This class implements the following interface:

```java
public interface BSTInterface<E> {
    boolean isEmpty();

    void insert(E element);
    void remove(E element);

    int size();
    int height();

    E smallestElement();

    Iterable<E> inOrder();
    Iterable<E> preOrder();
    Iterable<E> posOrder();

    Map<Integer, List<E>> nodesByLevel();
}
```

And so far I came up with the following:

```java
class MorseTree extends BST<MorseNode> {
    public MorseTree() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        BufferedReader in;
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/morse_V3.txt");
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        insert(new MorseNode(new String[]{"start"}));

        MorseNode last = root.getElement();
        in.lines().forEach(line -> {
            String[] temp = line.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ").split(" ");
            MorseNode w = new MorseNode(temp);

            for (int i = 0; i < temp[0].length(); i++) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(MorseNode element) {
        root = insert(element, root);
    }

    private Node<MorseNode> insert(MorseNode element, Node<MorseNode> node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return new Node<>(element, null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class MorseNode implements Comparable<MorseNode> {
    private String morse;
    private Character letter;
    private String tipo;

    public MorseNode(String[] word) {
        this.morse = word[0];
        this.letter = word[1].charAt(0);
        this.tipo = word[2];
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MorseNode o) {
        if (letter == o.letter) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Character.toString(letter);
    }
}
```

*([Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/tEsvw5x5))*

To build the tree I'm supposed to read a csv/txt file and insert it. From what I've gathered the idea is that I should implement a compareTo method in class in a way that the provided insert method would automatically insert it.

That's my problem. For two weeks now I've been trying and I just can't get an idea on how to compare two Morse strings.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Can you specify what the problem is? What's so hard about morse strings that you don't know how to compare them? You've explained more about your homework than your actual problem, don't expect people to just hand you the code

Comment: [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) implements `Comparable<String>`. Why not simply use that to compare the strings?

Comment: BST is a dictionary data structure for retrieving a value based on a given key. what is your key and what is your value?